# Any way to invoke Cloud Run Image with parameter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Lately I've been discovering the Google Cloud services to deploy my python analytics library.

So in my case I've several modules say that A, B and C. This every module takes different arguments in each initialization and they could run for like days.

It's hard to maintain the VM's since I have to start/stop them every time. Thought that Cloud Functions would be great, since it can be invoked with http queries as a parameter, however Function timeouts after max. 6 mins or so. The last option I've been considering is deploying my docker image to Cloud Run but in that case I couldn't find any way to pass the parameters as like in Cloud Functions...

So my question is; Is there any way I can invoke the Cloud Run image with my desired parameters (array of strings mostly) ?

Or is there any better recommendations considering the architecture.. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  You can certainly add data to the query string that invokes your Cloud Run service, just like you would with Cloud Functions.  But if you want to have a long-running service to do arbitrarily large amounts of computation, neither Cloud Functions nor Cloud Run are a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can invoke the Cloud Run image with my desired
> parameters?

Yes, add those strings as encoded query parameters when you invoke your Cloud Run application.

Note: The longest GET URL that Google accepts is 2048 characters. There are other limits to consider when creating HTTP requests [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#https-lb-header-limits). Limit your query string length to 1024 characters. See my comment [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#https-lb-header-limits).

If the data is longer than what Google supports in HTTP GET or POST methods, store a file on Cloud Storage and then provide a link to the location in the query parameter.

When you build a container, your goal is to make the container static and self-contained. The flexibility of providing environment variables is performed by the Docker command line, which does not exist in Cloud Run. Therefore you must provide dynamic environment configurations through another method.

If your goal is a compute-intensive application, Cloud Run is not the best choice, use Compute Engine. It is fairly easy to script starting a VM, launching a program, and automatically shutting down the VM. Compute Engine also supports running containers. I have environments where I install Docker on Compute Engine and then run containers via the Docker command remotely using scripted SSH commands. Easy to setup and configure.